# On InMobi Addtracker My application is not getting reported

Tags: android

I am using inmobi in my android application.
For that i am using InMobiAdTrackerAndroid.jar with this jar i am following documentation.

1: We are using following codes inmy application Launcher class 
IMAdTrackerUtil.setLogLevel(LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE);
IMAdTrackerAnalytics.getInstance().startSession(getApplicationContext(),Constants.INMOBI_APP_ID);

2: We are using this constants in place of above bold text
public static final String INMOBI_APP_ID = "5cd90875-04c7-476d-aa6e-ee7cf0ac70f6";

3: In AndroidManifest.xml class we add following code

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.inmobi.adtracker.androidsdk.IMAdTrackerInstallRefererReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

4: InMobiAdTrackerAndroid.jar is the library which we are using for inmobi and this library is added in build path.

On InMobi site in Reporting i am not getting an Application's name.(Application is present in DashBoard not present in Reporting)
I tested application using qrcode of my application and it forwarded me to google play where my application is present.
So what is the reason my application is not showing on Reportings.
here i a using samsung Tablet with sdk version 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a call to

```
IMAdTrackerAnalytics.getInstance().reportInstallGoal() 
and 
IMAdTrackerAnalytics.getInstance().reportGoal("Any custom goal").
```

Then you will see the reports in the UI. 
Install goal and all other custom goals defined by you,needs to be reported by the api call.

Also dont miss the following activty in the manifest

   
      
      
      
      
      
   

and the required permissions.

Hope this helps.